# How can I center a div container that contains floating divs with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve following with my code: I would like to have a div container, div#title-box, that is  centered. Inside that div container I want to have 3 other div containers, div#logo, div#title, div#subtitle (look at the code to see how exactly they are displayed)

Now the actual problem: The div#logo has a given width, the other two however don't, they float. 
How can I have have the div#title-box wrap around the other three divs but at the same time staying centered. Another problem I see is that the div#title-box cannot have a fixed width.

Any ideas. Thanks!

EDIT: The code below has to be modified so that the div#title-box wraps around the other divs and stays centered.

If anyone needs to play around with the code, here is it with a full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   div#title-box {
   max-width: 500px; 
   display: block;
   height: 600px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
   }

   div#logo {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 5px;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
   background: #ff0000 no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   border-radius: 15px;
   float: left;
   }

   div#title {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute; 
   left: 110px;   
   top: 100px;
   bottom: 20px;
   right: 10px;
   overflow: auto;
   float: left;
   }

   div#subtitle { 
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;    
   top: 140px;
   bottom: 20px;
   right: 10px;
   left: 110px;
   overflow: auto;
   float: left;
   }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="title-box">
  <div id="logo">
  </div>  
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>  
  <div id="subtitle">
    <h3>A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A!</h3>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I am unsure as to where you're heading at. What do you want to achieve? That the three divs don't float anymore?

Comment: The actual problem with my code is that the outermost div container does not wrap around the other divs. I want that it wraps around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something along the lines of

```
   div#title-box {
       width: 500px; 
       display: inline-block;
       height: 600px;
       margin: 0 25%;
       position: relative;
       left:-250px;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply

```
position: absolute
```

to your code, it will be put out of the rest of the DOM-context.

I have modified your CSS as such: http://jsfiddle.net/asBmS/. Your wrapping div now should always contain the child divs. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Well, first thanks. But what I am trying to achieve is that the layout of the divs stays as they are with my code. The only problem with my code is that there is more white space on the right than there is on the left side. This becomes more obvious when looking opening the HTML on a large screen.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can think to suggest is more of a 'hack' which would need to be adjusted if you change the width of the content.
Take a look at this link and see the offset margin-left, it puts everything in the center.
You'll probably need to tweak it further to meet your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/asBmS/15/

```
#logo,#title,#subtitle{
    /*offset hack*/
    margin-left: 10% !important;
}
```